# Very common ClassNofFoundError

Tags: command-line, classpath

I saw that there are many problems like that here.
Probably I didn't understand well the concept of classpath from the command line: "java Main.java -cp jbox2d-2.0.1-library-only.jar" (WORKS Well!)
"javac Main -cp jbox2d-2.0.1-library-only.jar" (DOES NOT WORK!)

Class:

```
import org.jbox2d.common.Vec2;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vec2 v = new Vec2();    
        System.out.println("Testando JAR com dependencias");
    }
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG3jC.png)

Answer (score 0):

(Solved) I solved at this site (in portuguese) http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-bibliotecas-jar-primeiros-passos/25339

The ".;" problem